# condition on a template in multi template class

Tags: c++, templates, std

A beginner question:

How to put a condition on a template in a multi-templated class:

I tried this:

```
template <class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<...>
class foo
{
};
```

And this:

```
template <class T,
          class U = std::enable_if<...>>
class foo
{
};
```

But they are not working. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you forgetting the `typename` in the second case but not in the first?

Comment: Well of course they're not working. For the first, you've randomly inserted `typename std::enable_if<...>` somewhere where it makes no sense. For the second, you've used `std::enable_if<...>` as the default for an argument that you'll specify explicitly, so the default doesn't get used. (Edit: re-reading this, it may be unintentionally harsh. Please read it in the spirit in which it was intended.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an additional template parameter defaulted to `void` and specialize it with `enable_if`:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename Enable = void>
class foo {};

template <typename T, typename U>
class foo<T, U, typename std::enable_if<...>::type>
{
};
```